# How to print out one part of a regex match, and a list of all other matches

Tags: text-processing

I am summarising some test results, so I have this type of text:

```
FAILED src/path/to/code.test.js
  Test Suite
     This test passed
    ✕ This test failed

• Test Suite › This test failed
  
  Expected: Foo
  Received: Bar
  
  <context>

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/path/to/code.test.js:31:415) // <-- I'm grabbing this line
```

I have a sed command `sed -nr 's/at.*? \((src.*?\.test.js)\:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+\)/\1/p' test-results.log | sort | unique -c | sort -rg | head -20` that will grab all the paths that start 'at' and end with ':<number>:<number>)' and I get a list of which *files* have the errors, and the counts.

```
23 src/path/to/code.test.js  
13 src/path/to/otherCode.test.js
```

I have also run the sed command and put the number *inside* the capture group and I get a list of file + line number (which is handy if one line is causing many issues).

```
20 src/path/to/code.test.js:31:415  
7 src/path/to/otherCode.test.js:9:26
6 src/path/to/otherCode.test.js:53:5
3 src/path/to/code.test.js:89:793
```

However, having to switch between these too is a pain.

Is there a way to get this kind of output:

```
23 src/path/to/code.test.js (20 - 31:415, 3 - 89:793)  
13 src/path/to/otherCode.test.js (7 - 9:26, 3 - 53:5)
```

Either by rolling up the `sed` output, or using a tool like `awk` (Arghh!).

I've found how to do the [basic search with `awk` on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5536068/1075247), but I'm not confident in how to even approach storing all the number matches, and then printing them out like the above.

My guess would be something like:

```c
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if($i==filePattern){
    split($1, a, ":")
    fileMatches[a[0]] = fileMatches[a[0]] - a[1]:a[2]
  }
} }' file
```

But that doesn't seem even close enough to work, given `$i==filePattern` is not a regex match.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: You should be doing everything with 1 awk command, please [edit] your question to provide sample input and the exact expected output given that input which we can simply copy/paste to test with so we can help you with that.

Comment: @EdMorton is the input and output I originally posted not sufficient?

Comment: No, the sample input you provided is a block of text under `I have this type of text` but then the output is `a list of file + line number`. If you want to get a list of file names plus line numbers output then you need to provide those files' contents as the sample input otherwise we don't have sample input we can copy/paste to run a potential solution against to see whether or not it produces the expected output you provided. Just showing us an example of what one input file might look like isn't adequate for us to test with.

Comment: Even for the 1 you show us, `src/path/to/code.test.js` you appear to show that the output line number should be either 20 or 23 (it's different in the 2 expected output blocks so idk which is correct) but there aren't 20+ lines in that input. If that leading number in the output is supposed to be a count of matches instead of line number, it's still not possible.

Comment: btw I see you using `.*?` a couple of times in your sed script. I'm not sure what you're hoping that means but it's actually undefined behavior as it's 2 contiguous repetition metacharacters (`*` = 0 or more then `?` = 0 or 1, so it might be interpreted as "0 or 1 repetitions of 0 or more repetitions" which makes no sense.) so your best hope would be for sed to ignore the `?` (in which case don't put it there) but it could do anything else with it.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the feedback, that's extremely helpful. I can't copy the example input over between my two machines, so unless I find a sample online I'm stuck.

Comment: You're welcome. The idea when posting a question is that you **create** a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. Any files you have lying around or can find online would have too much content that's irrelevant to your question and so dissuade many people from trying to help you and make it harder than necessary for the remaining few to do so. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and everything it says there about "code" also apply to sample input/output.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm well aware of that guidance, but for the reasons stated above I cannot follow them without writing out a chunk of my input character by character. By the time I've done that I might as well have done the text processing by hand.

Comment: That's not true. You have 1 example in your question already. Copy/paste another almost identical block to it if you can have multiple blocks in a file. Make a copy of it and modify the relevant lines and that's your 2nd input. Then just add the couple of lines of output given that  input. It'd take you less than 10 mins. Good luck either way.

Comment: Is your "desired output" block correct? You state you want line numbers concatenated with `:<number>:<number>`. So what do the leading digits in your "desired output" represent? It seems that these leading digits are superfluous--you can get the 'number' of problematic paths from how many  `<line number> | <number>:<number>` pairs you end up with, per path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]*at.*\(src.*\.test\.js:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\)/{
    split($0, tmp, /[)(:]/) ## Assuming there is no ), ( and : in the filePath
    fileCnt [tmp[2]]++
    fileErrs[tmp[2], tmp[3]":"tmp[4]]++
}

END{
    for (fileName in fileCnt){
        sep=""
        printf ("%s %s (", fileCnt[fileName], fileName)
        for(file in fileErrs){
            split(file, tmp, SUBSEP)
            if(fileName==tmp[1]){
                printf("%s - %s", sep fileErrs[file], tmp[2])
                sep=", "
            }
        }
        print ")"
    }
}' infile   ## or infiles*
```

---

The `fileCnt` associated array keeps the count of the files name only; the key of the array is the files' name and values are how many times they seen.
The `fileErrs` associated array keeps the count of the errors for each fileName; where the key is the combination of the fileName+errNums.

At the END block we are processing over the *fileCnt* array and print the file count with `fileCnt[fileName]` and then the fileName itself `fileName`; then we are processing the *fileErrs* array and split the key part which then we are comparing first part with fileName to find the indiviadual errors per each file.

Answer (score 2):

That's more of a job for `perl`:

```
perl -lne '
  if (/^\h*at\h.*?\((src.*?\.test\.js):(\d+:\d+)\)/) {
    $total{$1}++;
    $lines{$1}->{$2}++
  }
  END {
    for $file (sort {$total{$b} <=> $total{$a}} keys %total) {
      my $l = $lines{$file};
      print "$total{$file} $file (" . 
      join(", ", map "$l->{$_} - $_", sort {$l->{$b} <=> $l->{$a}} keys %$l) . ")"
    }
  }'
```

Note that `*?` as the non-greedy version of `*` is a perl regexp operator. I know of only one `sed` implementation which supports it (in addition to `-r` the non-standard equivalent of `-E`), but I doubt that's the one you're using. That's ast-open's `sed` which AFAIK is not shipped by default on any system, not even Illumos which has been known to include or at least consider including ast-open tools other than ksh93. In the GNU implementation of `sed` (the one that introduced the `-r` option), `.*?` is `?` (0 or 1 one of preceding atom) applied to `.*` (0 or more characters), so the same as `.*` and `.+?` (0 or 1 of 1 or more) would be the same as `.*` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'state %h; state $i; ++$i;  \
             if m/ ^ \h* at \h .*?  "(" ~ ")" [(src .*? \.test \.js) \: (\d+ \: \d+)] /   \
             -> { %h.push: $0 => $i ~"|"~ $1 }; END .say for %h;'  file
```

Briefly, code is run linewise over the input file using the (non-autoprinting) `-ne` command line flags. A hash `%h` is stated. An iterator `$i` is stated. For each line, the `$i` iterator is incremented. An `if` conditional tests for a match to a regex ***similar-if-not-identical*** to the Perl5 code posted by @Stephane_Chazelas. However this Raku regex uses one nice (newer) feature--Raku's `~` tilde syntax for nested data structures: `"(" ~ ")" [ … ]`. The Raku regex will capture the path into `$0` and the colon-separated digits into `$1`.

When a (linewise) match is found it is `push`ed onto the `%h` hash: the `$0` (path) is used as a key, while the value becomes the line number concatenated (with `~`) to the `$1` digits portion of the capture, using the code: `$i ~"\t"~ $1`. Since duplicate keys cannot exist in the hash, different values accumulate per key (i.e path). At the `END` of reading lines, the `%h` hash is output.

Sample Input:

```
#See above. OP's original file was concatenated 5 times, 
#one record was altered (path and digits).
```

Sample Output (1):

```
src/path/to/code.test.js => [13|31:415 27|31:415 55|31:415 69|31:415]
src/path/to/othercode.test.js => 41|32:416
```

To get a leading column of counts, replace the code after `END` with the following:

```
for %h.kv -> $k,$v {say $v.elems, "\t", $k => $v};
```

Sample Output (2):

```
4   src/path/to/code.test.js => [13|31:415 27|31:415 55|31:415 69|31:415]
1   src/path/to/othercode.test.js => 41|32:416
```

*[Note: Generally `say` produces arrow-separated `key => value` output where hashes are concerned. Above you can get tab-separated key-value output simply by changing the final `say` command(s) to `put`].*

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Tilde_for_nesting_structures
https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://raku.org